# unable to import package after Using legacy 'setup.py install'

Tags: import, package, legacy

I am unable to import yfinance or multitasking. I used pip install yfinance and it downloaded and installed everything but I got this message regarding yfinance and multitasking. I am using Spyder and it is unable to import these 2 but able to import everything else.

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for yfinance, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for multitasking, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pytz, six, python-dateutil, numpy, pandas, charset-normalizer, certifi, idna, urllib3, requests, multitasking, lxml, yfinance
    Running setup.py install for multitasking ... done
    Running setup.py install for yfinance ... done
Successfully installed certifi-2021.5.30 charset-normalizer-2.0.4 idna-3.2 lxml-4.6.3 multitasking-0.0.9 numpy-1.21.1 pandas-1.3.1 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2021.1 requests-2.26.0 six-1.16.0 urllib3-1.26.6 yfinance-0.1.63
```

I installed the wheel package after, but can't seem to do anything about yfinance or multitasking.